# Trouble with the ios-share-extension plugin 2019

Tags: ios, cordova, share, share-extension

Has anyone figured out how to get the share extension working for iOS and ionic? I've tried a few plugins for cordova. It displays my app as sharable but the window to share content is never displayed.